# How to change default path of command line tool in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a command line tool called ffmpeg, for example, that has this location on my mac:

```
/Users/me/anaconda/bin/ffmpeg
```

I also have ffmpeg installed here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/
```

When I type ffmpeg into the command line, the default path it uses is the first one. how do I change it so the ffmpeg it uses is the second path? ie when I type which ffmpeg, it gives the second path.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to change your path precedence, you can make an alias in your .bashrc file or .profile file

alias ffmpg=/path_to_it/ffmpg

otherwise you need to look at your .bashrc or .profile and look for where PATH is being set, then change the path order to have the one you want executed 1st.

Comment: You can also code it as an exported function or add a link (symbolic or direct) in an even higher precedence directory. These have the advantage that the correct copy will run in a subshell, such as a script will invoke. Alternatively, rename the version you don't want to use, allowing you to use it when you want, by specifying the renamed name. Note that if you use an alias `which ffmpeg` will show the wrong version, though `type ffmpeg` will identify the alias.